# Google Directory API User list orgDepartment returns undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm looping through the user list to pull out some data.

```
Logger.log('\nName : %s\nEmail : %s\nOU : %s\nDepartment : %s\n', users[i].name.fullName, users[i].primaryEmail, users[i].orgUnitPath, users[i].orgDepartment);
```

Name, email and OU return the expected results but not Department.

Some user accounts have department data and others don't but in any case the result always comes back 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong ?

Full code here.

```
function listUsers(){
  var values = [],
  users = [],
  userListQuery = {},
  nextPageToken = '',
  listObject = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    query: "isSuspended=false",
    maxResults: 500
  },
  i = 0,
  j = 0;

do {

if (nextPageToken && nextPageToken !== '') {
  listObject.pageToken = nextPageToken;
}  

var userListQuery = AdminDirectory.Users.list(listObject);

// Si plus de maxResults retourner à nextPageToken
nextPageToken = userListQuery.nextPageToken;

// Ajout de résultats à la liste
users = users.concat(userListQuery.users);

} while (nextPageToken);

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
// Filtrer les résultats
if (users[i].orgUnitPath == '/') {
  j++;
  Logger.log('Résultat #%s', j.toString());
  Logger.log('\nNom : %s\nCourriel : %s\nOU : %s\nDépartement : %s\n', users[i].name.fullName, users[i].primaryEmail, users[i].orgUnitPath, users[i].orgDepartment);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

`Users` resource doesn't have top-level property `orgDepartment`. Although you can *search* users using `orgDepartment` (as well as `address` or other `org`-prefixed fields), it is not defined in the returned object (hence the `undefined` value).

**Solution**

Access the top-level property `organizations`, which is an `Array<Object>` (organizations this user is a part of). Its elements are structured as follows (obviously, you need the `department` property):

```
{
  "name": string,
  "title": string,
  "primary": boolean,
  "type": string,
  "customType": string,
  "department": string,
  "symbol": string,
  "location": string,
  "description": string,
  "domain": string,
  "costCenter": string,
  "fullTimeEquivalent": integer
}
```

Assuming there is only one organization associated with the user, referencing department should look like: `users[i].organizations[0].department`

**Reference**

1. `Users` resource representation [reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users);
2. Searching for `Users` fields [reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#fields);